# Tcl: Why is the dollar sign used in the first argument to `upvar`?

Tags: scope, tcl, upvar

The `tcl` [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.html) provide the following example on how to use the `upvar` command:

```
proc add2 name {
    upvar $name x
    set x [expr {$x + 2}]
}
```

Inside this procedure, `x` acts as a reference to the variable `name` which belongs to the scope *outside* of `add2`.

I don't understand why the first argument to `upvar` has to be provided with the dollar sign, and the second argument not. Shouldn't it simply be `upvar name x`, since we are referencing `name` rather than its value?

Comment: The _value_ in `name` is just a string, that happens to be the name of a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how add2 might be used:

```
(Tcl) 2 % set fred 3
3
(Tcl) 3 % add2 fred
5
```

Here add2 is called with its parameter called "name" set to the value "fred".  If the code then did `upvar name x` it would be operating on a variable literally called "name" but we need it to operate on the variable called "fred" so we write `$name` to get the value "fred" from the parameter called "name".

Comment: I understand what you mean. Adding `puts $name` before the `upvar` call returned `fred` which I didn't expect. This is different from other programming languages... So is `fred` a variable? Or a string?

Answer (score 1):

Donal's answer might be illustrated this way:

```
proc addfred {} {
   upvar fred fr
   incr fr 2
}
% set fred 3
3
% addfred
5
proc addfred {} {
   upvar "fred" fr
   incr fr 2
}
% addfred
7
```

I.e. you need not have the upvar-ed variable in the proc's parameters at all, to make it work.

With "level" option of upvar, you can add even more resourcefulness to this.

Comment: The only common levels are `1` (parent) and `#0` (global); you also see `0` and `#1` sometimes in general code (the former is for local variable aliasing, and the latter has some use in coroutines). Others are very rare and usually a sign of other problems in the code because of how specific they tend to be.